# rssfeed using php / how to access certain data

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

I am trying to parse https://www.joc.com/rssfeed.  There are a couple of things I cannot seem to access.  For example, how would I access (1) <dc:creator>**Keith Wallis, Special Correspondent |** Jul 30, 2021 3:16PM EDT </dc:creator>  and also [caption caption= ][/caption]?  I cannot seem to figure out how to access.  So far I have the below code:

I have the following code:

```
function display_rss_card(){
    
    ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0');
    $rss = simplexml_load_file('https://www.joc.com/rssfeed');

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
        if($i<9){
            $x = $item->description->children();
            
            echo '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">';
            echo '      <img class="card-img-top" src="'.$x->img['src'].'" alt="Girl in a jacket" alt="Card image cap">';
            echo '      <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>';
            echo '      <div class="card-body">';
            echo '          <h5 class="card-title">'.$item->title.'</h5>';
            echo '          <p class="card-text">
                            Published: '.$item->pubDate.' / '.$item->description.' 
                            </p>';
            echo '      <a href="'.$item->link.'">Read More...</a>';
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<br/>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```